# Groovy Binding: Cannot cast object with class 'custompackage.CustomClass' to class 'custompackage.CustomClass'

Tags: groovy

Using Groovy Binding to execute scripts from a main controller and attempting to pass a custom object, I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'custompackage.CustomClass@60099951' with class 'custompackage.CustomClass' to class 'custompackage.CustomClass'
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Controller.groovy
import custompackage.CustomClass
CustomClass test = new CustomClass()

def binding = new Binding()
def engine = new GroovyScriptEngine('./src')

binding.setProperty("test", test)

engine.run("CustomScript.groovy", binding)
```

The file being run with above:

```
// CustomScript.groovy
import custompackage.CustomClass
CustomClass t 

if(!binding.variables.containsKey("test")){
    t = new CustomClass()
} else {        
    t = test
}
```

I'm defining the `CustomClass t` at the beginning for the purpose of autocomplete in my IDE. When running as `def t` it works fine.

I know the object is being passed correctly, due to the exception (and further printing of the object)

The error occurs on `t = test`

Why is Groovy trying to cast an object of the same type to it's type, and then failing to do so? And is there a fix that will still allow me to keep the statically typed `t`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `custompackage.CustomClass` in `Controller.groovy` is not the same as in `CustomScript.groovy`.

I checked the class instances in `CustomScript.groovy` with the debugger and found something interesting:

```
def a = CustomClass.class // Debugger: a={Class@1499} "class custompackage.CustomClass"
def b = test.class        // Debugger: b={Class@1187} "class custompackage.CustomClass"
```

While when using `GroovyShell` instead of `GroovyScriptEngine` in `Controller.groovy` I get:

```
def a = CustomClass.class // Debugger: a={Class@1185} "class custompackage.CustomClass"
def b = test.class        // Debugger: b={Class@1185} "class custompackage.CustomClass"
```

and the assignment `t = test` works without error.

The `Controller.groovy` file using `GroovyShell` looks like this:

```
// Controller.groovy
import custompackage.CustomClass
CustomClass test = new CustomClass()

def binding = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

binding.setProperty("test", test)

shell.evaluate(new File("CustomScript.groovy"))
```

I checked the documentation of `GroovyScriptEngine` and found a constructor which takes a `ClassLoader` as argument. Maybe that's the way to go but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't noticed that. I assumed the @number was something to do with the instance of the object. Switched to using `GroovyShell` as this suits my needs. Thanks much!